# Electric polarization in terms of berry phase?

Tags: condensed-matter, polarization, topological-insulators

I was reading a text  in which Electric polarization  in terms of Berry phase was defined as

$P=\frac{e}{2\pi}\sum_{n}\int A_n (k) dk$

under gauge transformation $P\rightarrow P+ne$ (which means polarization can't be defined because it is not gauge invariant quantity) but in the text they defined  polarization  as $P mod(e\times integer)$ I am having trouble understanding this $mod$ argument ,

How  can  polarization is defined as $Pmod(e\times integer)$?

Comment: It means polarization can only be defined up to $ne$; the fractional part can not be changed by gauge transformations.

Comment: Could you specify the text you read?